# Join on max value in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-ase15

I have been trying to join based on max column values of a table
Here is my table structure

Table A:

```
| ID | Val | text |
| 1  | 423 | tuh  |
| 2  | 369 | foo  |
| 3  | 568 | bars |
| 4  | 789 | ther |
```

Table B:

```
| Val | Label |
| 423 | Adria |
| 369 | Adria |
| 568 | Adria |
| 789 | Bang  |
```

Table C:

```
| Label | Val |
| Adria | 100 |
| Fox   | 123 |
| Bang  | 789 |
```

I have tried this query and for some reason I still do not get the result based on max val in table A

```
select C.Label, A.txt
from C join
     B
     on B.Label = C.Label left join
     A
     on A.Val = B.Val and
     A.Val = (select max(A.Val) from A as a where a.Val = A.val)
where C.Lable = 'Adria'
```

Output:

```
Adria tuh
Adria foo
Adria bars
```

Expected Output:

```
Adria bars
```

Could someone please help point out what am I missing?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks for the edit. I have added the tag

Comment: Your code as written should do what you want.  I suspect you have not transcribed correctly your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Nope, it is not working. I am still getting the wrong output. I have put the query correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** complete rewrite after question updated with more data (see edit history if really interested in my prior ramblings).

---

Assumptions/Understandings:

- `A.Val` is unique (eg, there is only one row where `A.Val = 423`) otherwise we'll need more info for the join from `B` to `A` (eg, if 3x rows have `A.Val = 423` do we return 3 rows/`A.text` values, or do we limit the match to a single row via additional criteria?)
- if no match in table `A` then return `A.text = NULL` (hence the `left join`)

Where I need more input from OP is on the `B->A` join.  From OP's comment we know that for `Label = 'Adria'` we want to pull the row from `A` where `Val = max(Val) = 568`, but what I'm not sure about is if I can apply the `max()` to `B.Val` or do I need to apply the `max()` to `A.Val`:

- limit the `B->A` join to `A.Val = max(B.Val)` **or** ...
- limit the `B->A` join to `A.Val = max(A.Val)`

---

One idea for *limit the `B->A` join to `A.Val = max(B.Val)`*

```
select  CB.Label, A.text
from    (select C.Label, max(B.Val) as maxVal
         from    C
         join    B
         on      C.Label = B.Label
         and     C.Label = 'Adria'
         group by C.Label) as CB
left
join    A
on      A.Val = CB.maxVal
go

 Label      text
 ---------- ----------
 Adria      bars
```

If we `delete A where Val = 568` (so that `A.Val = max(B.Val) = 568` fails) the query returns:

```
 Label      text
 ---------- ----------
 Adria      NULL
```

---

One idea for *limit the `B->A` join to `A.Val = max(A.Val)`*

```
select  dt.Label, A.text
from    (select C.Label, max(A.Val) as maxVal
         from   C
         join   B
         on     C.Label = B.Label
         and    C.Label = 'Adria'
         left
         join   A
         on     A.Val = B.Val
         group by C.Label) as dt
left
join    A
on      A.Val = dt.maxVal
go

 Label      text
 ---------- ----------
 Adria      bars
```

If we `delete A where Val = 568` (so that `A.Val = dt.maxVal = 423`) the query returns:

```
 Label      text
 ---------- ----------
 Adria      tuh
```

If we `delete A` (so that `A.Val = dt.maxVal` fails) the query returns:

```
 Label      text
 ---------- ----------
 Adria      NULL
```

**NOTE:** Above queries (barring any cut-n-paste typos on my behalf) were run on `ASE 15.7 SP140`.

Comment: Kudos for the well structured answer. Yes, it's silly of me to have that MAX clause in the query (423 =423). However to answer your questions
1. Yes, it's possible to not find rows in A sometimes, Hence left join
2. As you can see from the sample data, 'Adria' has multiple mappings in A. I need to filter only on the max Val i.e., 568 hence the reason to use MAX.
3. Yes the data is huge, but the query is same as the one I have put here.

Comment: I have edited the sample data, just to give you an better idea about the data my tables has

Answer (score -1):

Your query should work, although the condition is redundant:

```
a.val = A.val
```

This is both referencing the table in the subquery.  So, it is equivalent to `1=1`.  Actually, it is really equivalent to `a.val is not null`.

Because of this condition, I think you have made an error in transcribing your query into the question.

You can do what you want more simply using `TOP`:

```
select C.Label, A.txt
from C join
     B
     on B.Label = C.Label left join
     (select top (1) a.*
      from A
      order by val desc
     ) a
     on A.Val = B.Val 
where C.Label = 'Adria';
```

Comment: I am getting an error for this answer   Incorrect syntax near "."

Comment: @KnowNothing . . . Except for the misspelling in the `where` clause -- which I'm fixing -- this code works as written (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=658b2154a86257aed4ca051326c3db81).

Comment: Strange it works in the fiddle and not in my DB. Is there any other method to achieve this without using top or limit? The reason being if i had same vals for two different texts, i would want to show all of them

Comment: @KnowNothing . . . Perhaps the parentheses around `1` don't work in Sybase?

Comment: I did try that, now it says "An order by clause isn't allowed in a derived table"
very strange as top is used for exactly that. To use order by in a sub query

Comment: @KnowNothing, You can use TOP and order by with your outer query as well.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i won't be able to use WHERE IN clause if I use top in outer query. 'Adria' is a sample value

Comment: @KnowNothing . . . Interesting.  That is a very curious limitation in Sybase that I don't recall.